# Flutter ignore padding or margin without using stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart, padding, margin

is there a way to ignore parent widget margin or padding without using stack? what i tried it to achieve it but couldn't success:

it is just moving widget on x axis regarding the padding of parent.

```
Container(
   height: 5,
   color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
   transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
   ),
```